# HTML show/hide parts of a table onclick of table headers

Tags: javascript, html

I have a nested HTML table. I would like to show parts of the nested table depending on the header clicked using javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/TtWTR/103/

so far it shows all three parts. I want to click header `A` and show only `optionA`, click header`B` and only show `optionB` etc etc. Not sure if ive set it up right as all three are showing. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option oh hide() and show() methods

```
   $('.trigger').click(function() {
             console.log($(this).text())
      var selectedHdr = $(this).text();
      $('.nested tr').hide();
      $('.nested tr#'+selectedHdr).show();       
        });
```

https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/vdabJQ

Comment: this worked but is there a way i can get one of those options to show by default? for example when the user visits the page with the table, i want A to display by default

Answer (score 0):

Usually I find it convenient to use CSS class selectors on the "root" element (in your case that would be `.toptable`) allowing you to toggle it to show and hide child elements.

```
<table class="toptable">
    <tr class="accordion">
        <td class="A trigger">A</td>
        <td class="B trigger">B</td>
        <td class="C trigger">C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
             <table>
                  <tr class="content A">
                      <!-- will toggle using show-A -->
                  </tr>
             </table
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then you can make sure to hide the `.content` rows using CSS unless specific classes are set on the top table:

```
.content {
    display: none; /* content hidden by default */
}

.show-A .A.content {
    display: table; /* show when the parent table has .show-A set */
}
```

Now you just have to add event listeners to your triggers to toggle the classes for the different content rows:

```js
const toptable = document.querySelector('.toptable');

['A', 'B', 'C'].forEach((group) => {
    const trigger = document.querySelector(`.${group}.trigger`);
    trigger.addEventListener('click', () => {
        toptable.classList.toggle(`show-${group}`);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the following script

```
        $('.nested').hide();
        $('tr .trigger').click(function() {
            var target_id= "#"+$(this).attr('id')+"-table";
            $('.nested').not(target_id).hide();
            $(target_id).show();
        });
```

and is shown in http://jsfiddle.net/TtWTR/152/